# Create a list of links from the page https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets/performer/2764/ that contain the text New York Rangers

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup, webdriverwait

i'm trying to create a list in python of all links from a page that contain a certain string. For example I'd like all links that contain "New York Rangers @" from this page https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets/performer/2764/ .

Thanks for all the help - sorry if this is a dumb question but couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: You should add what you've tried/thought so far to the question :)

Comment: Also, we need some clarification. What should contain a certain string? The text inside of the `<a>`  tag? The url itself?

Comment: apologies, first post so still figuring out protocol. It would be within the <a> tag.

Comment: No worries, Rich! You should click on the "edit" button right under your question to add these clarifications. Welcome to Stack Overflow! :D

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is embedded within the page inside the `<srcipt>` tag. You can use this example to parse the data (with `re` and `json` modules):

```
import re
import json
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0'}
url = 'https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets/performer/2764/'

txt = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

data = json.loads(re.search(r'window.__INITIAL_STATE__\s*=\s*(.*})<', txt)[1])

# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4)) # <-- uncomment to see all data (prices, dates, etc.)

for event in data['EVENT_SEO_LIST']['events']:
    if 'PARKING PASSES ONLY' in event['name']:
        continue
    print('{:<45} {}'.format(event['name'], 'https://www.stubhub.com/' + event['webURI']))
```

Prints:

```
Detroit Red Wings at New York Rangers         https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-1-31-2020/event/104217508/
New York Rangers at Detroit Red Wings         https://www.stubhub.com/detroit-red-wings-tickets-detroit-red-wings-detroit-little-caesars-arena-2-1-2020/event/104215245/
Dallas Stars at New York Rangers              https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-2-3-2020/event/104212773/
Toronto Maple Leafs at New York Rangers       https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-2-5-2020/event/104215469/
Buffalo Sabres at New York Rangers            https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-2-7-2020/event/104217518/
Los Angeles Kings at New York Rangers         https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-2-9-2020/event/104214839/
New York Rangers at Winnipeg Jets Tickets (Replica Hall of Fame Banner Giveaway) https://www.stubhub.com/winnipeg-jets-tickets-winnipeg-bell-mts-place-2-11-2020/event/104212882/
New York Rangers at Minnesota Wild            https://www.stubhub.com/minnesota-wild-tickets-minnesota-wild-saint-paul-xcel-energy-center-2-13-2020/event/104216234/
New York Rangers at Columbus Blue Jackets     https://www.stubhub.com/columbus-blue-jackets-tickets-columbus-blue-jackets-columbus-nationwide-arena-2-14-2020/event/104212942/
Boston Bruins at New York Rangers             https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-2-16-2020/event/104217520/
New York Rangers at Chicago Blackhawks        https://www.stubhub.com/chicago-blackhawks-tickets-chicago-blackhawks-chicago-united-center-2-19-2020/event/104213910/
New York Rangers at Carolina Hurricanes       https://www.stubhub.com/carolina-hurricanes-tickets-carolina-hurricanes-raleigh-pnc-arena-2-21-2020/event/104212812/
San Jose Sharks at New York Rangers           https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-2-22-2020/event/104217524/
New York Rangers at New York Islanders        https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-islanders-tickets-new-york-islanders-uniondale-nycb-live-home-of-the-nassau-veterans-memorial-coliseum-2-25-2020/event/104354662/
New York Rangers at Montreal Canadiens        https://www.stubhub.com/montreal-canadiens-tickets-montreal-bell-centre-2-27-2020/event/104215418/
New York Rangers at Philadelphia Flyers       https://www.stubhub.com/philadelphia-flyers-tickets-philadelphia-flyers-philadelphia-wells-fargo-center-philadelphia-2-28-2020/event/104212712/
Philadelphia Flyers at New York Rangers       https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-3-1-2020/event/104215027/
St. Louis Blues at New York Rangers           https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-3-3-2020/event/104217528/
Washington Capitals at New York Rangers       https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-3-5-2020/event/104215030/
New Jersey Devils at New York Rangers         https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-3-7-2020/event/104215474/
New York Rangers at Dallas Stars              https://www.stubhub.com/dallas-stars-tickets-dallas-stars-dallas-american-airlines-center-3-10-2020/event/104214902/
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to get the content of the webpage you want to search the links. I highly recommend using [requests](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/), a simple HTTP library for Python:

```py
import requests

response = request.get(https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets/performer/2764/)
```

This specific URL for some reason requires a User-Agent header, so you should send one on the request:

```py
url = 'https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets/performer/2764/'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0'
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent':user_agent})
```

Then you can start analyzing the content of the page using [beautifulsoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). You can use the method `find_all` passing a compiled regular expression as the `text` parameter to find all `a` tags that contains a certain text:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
rangers_anchor_tags = soup.find_all("a", text=re.compile(r".*\bNew York Rangers at\b.*")
urls = [anchor["href"] for anchor in rangers_anchor_tags]
```

`urls`, then, would be a list of URLs that the respective inner text of the anchor tag contains the string in question.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you won't need [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) and to create a list of all links i.e. `href` attributes from the page https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets/performer/2764/ that contains the text **New York Rangers** you need to to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  # configuring the driver for optimum results
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')   
  driver.get("https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets/performer/2764/")

  # just one line of code
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[./div[contains(., 'New York Rangers')]]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-1-31-2020/event/104217508/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/detroit-red-wings-tickets-detroit-red-wings-detroit-little-caesars-arena-2-1-2020/event/104215245/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-2-3-2020/event/104212773/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-2-5-2020/event/104215469/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-2-7-2020/event/104217518/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-2-9-2020/event/104214839/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/winnipeg-jets-tickets-winnipeg-bell-mts-place-2-11-2020/event/104212882/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/minnesota-wild-tickets-minnesota-wild-saint-paul-xcel-energy-center-2-13-2020/event/104216234/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/columbus-blue-jackets-tickets-columbus-blue-jackets-columbus-nationwide-arena-2-14-2020/event/104212942/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-2-16-2020/event/104217520/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/chicago-blackhawks-tickets-chicago-blackhawks-chicago-united-center-2-19-2020/event/104213910/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/carolina-hurricanes-tickets-carolina-hurricanes-raleigh-pnc-arena-2-21-2020/event/104212812/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-2-22-2020/event/104217524/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-islanders-tickets-new-york-islanders-uniondale-nycb-live-home-of-the-nassau-veterans-memorial-coliseum-2-25-2020/event/104354662/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/montreal-canadiens-tickets-montreal-bell-centre-2-27-2020/event/104215418/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/philadelphia-flyers-tickets-philadelphia-flyers-philadelphia-wells-fargo-center-philadelphia-2-28-2020/event/104212712/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-3-1-2020/event/104215027/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-3-3-2020/event/104217528/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-3-5-2020/event/104215030/', 'https://www.stubhub.com/new-york-rangers-tickets-new-york-rangers-new-york-madison-square-garden-3-7-2020/event/104215474/']
  ```